# How to "tap" a list item within a list item?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, click

The **purpose** of the code is a menu dropdown.

The dropdown menu works in a normal browser on a desktop. However, `items[1].children('a')` is not calling the function.

Here is the important part:

```
if ($('body').hasClass('mobile')) {
    $(items[0].children('a'), items[1].children('a')).each(function() {
        $(this).on('vclick', function(e) {
            var menu = $(this).parent();
```

Here is the full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/G6w9M/

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this it would be more helpful.

Comment: @NiranjanBorawake I don't know why I didn't. I added a jsfiddle. That simplified the post a lot.

Comment: This isn't related to jquery-mobile. Please read more about jquery-mobile.

Comment: @Omar It is related to jquery-mobile. The `vclick` function is from jquery-mobile and I am having an issue of a list item listening to `vclick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to combine the two elements with this line

```
 $(items[0].children('a'), items[1].children('a'))
```

but you are not. (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)

You are using the second as the context in which to search for the first..

Use an array to combine them or the `.add()` method

```
$([items[0].children('a'), items[1].children('a')])
```

or

```
$(items[0].children('a')).add(items[1].children('a'))
```